# Codeigniter 3, ubuntu - mail is sent using native PHP mail function, but not with CI Email class

Tags: php, codeigniter, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I can send email via native PHP function, but when I try using CI Email class, mail is not sent. I am using Ubuntu on Amazon EC2 server.

Using PHP (working):

```
$to      = 'test@test.com'; // mail address I am using is real
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Codeigniter (not working):

```
$this->load->library('email');

$config['protocol']  = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_port'] = '25';
$config['mailtype']  = 'html';
$this->email->from('your@example.com', 'Your Name');
$this->email->to('imalimalomrk@gmail.com');
$this->email->subject('Email Test');
$this->email->message('Testing the email class.');
$this->email->initialize($config);
var_dump($this->email->send());
```

Comment: instead of do a var_dump of the send function, do a `var_dump($this->email->print_debugger())` after `$this->email->send()`

Answer (score 0):

What if `var_dump()` is removed and left `$this->email->send()` only?
Optionally, you can load and use [email helper](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/email_helper.html) instead that will allow you using sending mail in more (PHP) native way.